# TFS check-in policy automatic resolving

Tags: tfs, tdd

Recently our TFS admin added a new check in policy that any check in should be associated with a TFS work item.
after a while I found myself wasting a lot of time searching for those general work items that should be associated by default to any check in and for the work item of that specific project.

I would like to know if it's possible to set some roles that will be added to any check in that I'm performing.

I would like to set 2 kinds of associations:

1. Specific file name --> all "trigger.ini" files should have work item id 1
2. all items under a root folder --> all files in folder "AProject" should be associated with work item id 2 and all files in folder "BProject" should be associated with work item id 3

it would save me lots of time because I'm working in TDD and after any refactoring of a passed test I'm performing a check in.

someone know if it's possible or not?

Comment: Did you mean you want to find a general work item  that suitable for  any check in? And the work item should including the  specific file name. Moreover, what's the mean of  2.all items under a root folder? Could you explain more clear?

Comment: is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your requirement is too complicated. There are no such roles to achieve it automatically.

You may have to manually associate workitem  with your changeset. A slightly faster way: using the "My Work" page. Before you start coding you select a work item from "Available Work Items" to "In Progress". From there you can directly jump to the "Pending Changes" page by clicking "Check In". It is also possible to suspend your work where the state of the IDE is saved.

A demo for your reference: [Multi-tasking with My Work](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-How-to-multi-task-with-My-Work)